# Listbox item move is moving the wrong items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have some C# functions that are supposed to move `ListItems` from one ASP.NET `ListBox` to another, and this is what they look like:

```
protected void btnSelectRec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListedItem(lbPotRecips, lbRecips);
}
protected void btnDeselectRec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoveListedItem(lbRecips, lbPotRecips);
}
private void MoveListedItem(ListBox lbSender, ListBox lbReceiver)
{
    List<ListItem> removed = new List<ListItem>();
    foreach (ListItem item in lbSender.Items)
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
            lbReceiver.Items.Add(item);
            removed.Add(item);
        }
    foreach (ListItem item in removed)
        lbSender.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

I've noticed in my tests that this only seems to work about 3/5 of the time.
Though, since there are plenty of times when I click something on `lbSender`, then `btnSelectRec`, and the item move initiates.
But, sometimes the item on `lbReceiver` is completely different.

I looked and saw this might have something to do with my scroll position, which can cause the `foreach` loop to mess up and think, for ex, that **the second item in view is the second in the list overall**, when this is completely wrong.

For a moment I thought the `listbox` was being weirdly specific about the position of the item selected, but considering that this issue only sometimes occurs regardless of my position, I'm now at a loss with what could be causing this mismatch. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some of the errors / information that you are seeing when debugging?

Comment: @haydnD that's the hardest part: there are no outright errors that show up when this happens. The program simply thinks that (for ex) I've selected the second item in the listbox overall when really the item is just the second thing listed that I can see.